# Get checked values from array

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using mvc and I'm trying to loop through a array of checkboxes, but how do I exclude the ones that are "false" in that list?

```
for(int i = 0; i < TimeRange1.Length; i++)
        {
          if(TimeRange1[i] == "false" ....??)
        // dostuff
        }
```

or is there some better way of doing it?

/M

Comment: if TimeRange1 is a checkbox array (see Tim S. Van Haren) then you should use better names like cbTimeRanges

Comment: Please show the relevant portion of your view.  Specifically, the Html.CheckBox() helper is meant to render only single checkboxes and *must not* be used to render a collection of checkboxes with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing it with MVC - you could make `TimeRange1` a `bool[]`.

Then, you could always do this with linq

```
var newItems = TimeRange1.Select(i => i == false);

foreach(var item in newItems)
{
 ....
}
```

or you could simplify it

```
foreach(var item in TimeRange1.Select(i => i == false))
{
 ....
}
```

Comment: how do I get: foreach(var item in TimeRange1.Select(i => i != "false"))  to work? I cant seem to get hold of the value

Comment: You can't `not` a string value. Remove the quotes.

Comment: ...& change the type of `TimeRange1`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `TimeRange1` is your `CheckBox[]`, try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TimeRange1.Length; i++)
{
    if (TimeRange1[i] == "on")
    {
       // dostuff
    }
}
```